# auto increment works not properly while insert data into multiple tables at once

Tags: mysql

Some notes: I use INSERT IGNORE because i am avoiding of inserting duplicates. 'bookID', 'libraryID and 'personID' are auto increment and primary keys.

Let's say I have three tables in my db.

Table 1 'books':

```
bookID | bookTitle
     1 | 1st book
     2 | 2nd book
```

..........

Table 2 'libraries':

```
libraryID | bookID(from table 'book') | libraryName
        1 |                         1 | 1st library
        2 |                         1 | 2nd library
        3 |                         2 | 2nd library
```

.............

Table 3 'rental':

```
personID | libraryID(from table 'libraries') | personName
       1 |                                 2 | John
       2 |                                 3 | Shaq
```

.................

I am trying to insert data in three tables at once using query below:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO books (bookID,bookTitle)
VALUES ("",
        "1st book");

INSERT
IGNORE INTO libraries (libraryID,bookID,libraryName)
VALUES ("",
          (SELECT bookID
           FROM books
           WHERE bookTitle="1st book"),"1st library");

INSERT
IGNORE INTO rental (personID,libraryID,personName)
VALUES ("",
          (SELECT libraryID
           FROM libraries
           WHERE libraryName="1st library"
             AND bookID=
               (SELECT bookID
                FROM books
                WHERE bookTitle="1st book")),"Mark");
```

This query works. I am inserting thousands of rows. Problem is ID. I am leaving 'bookID', 'libraryID' and 'personID' values empty in query and expecting it to be integer sequence, I mean: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,... However, I got this: 1,5,100,152,1112,3456,... All ID's are random numbers and not normal sequence. This thing happens in all three tables. I guess I need to fix my query somehow.

Is it possible to fix query to work as I want?

EDIT:
When I started to use newer version of MySQL (version 4.1.5) problem gone. Above written query works as I want (no auto_increment problem for my anymore).
Thanks for your suggestions guys. I appreciate that.

Comment: The auto id field is increased by one just when you first time insert the data or after you reset the auto increment field. If you for example delete last row (with id 9) and insert new one, the new id will be 10. And id 9 will not be reused even it does not exist anymore.

Comment: Yes, I know that when you delete record that id won't be reused. But I definitely didn't delete so much rows. Now I have a huge ID jumps: 1, 100, 1000, 3000 and so on. I know that something wrong with query but can't figure out that.

Comment: Try loosing the id fields from insert (or inserting with ```null``` values) like this: 
```INSERT IGNORE INTO books (bookTitle)
VALUES ("1st book");```

Comment: Also note, that when ignore is used, on duplicate key (or any other error) no entry is registered, but the ```auto_increment``` key increases. Is it possible, that you try to insert a lot of entries that end up in error?

Comment: what server side language are you using? Why not just insert the data and get newly inserted id from the insert clause/function and then use that id to build relations. I think that's common way to do things.

Comment: rekaszeru, yes I am inserting a lot duplicates. Is it possible to avoid auto_increment key increasing?

Comment: @arunelis, you cannot avoid the increasing if you call statements that raise errors, but you can work it around. Please see my answer on how to do it.

Comment: PHP language. Hardy, if I understood correctly, you are suggesting to insert books into table separately and then use it. I have hundred thousands of books and I keep getting it every day, so I am trying to think a fast way to insert all data to db and don't worry about duplicates. My goal is tu get exel file with thousands of books, libraries and persons, prepare queries per 1 minute and insert it into db.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use any title related checks in insertions (without using id:s). That just doesn't work if you for example insert two books with same title.

Common way would be like:

- insert book without specifying ID and get the new, auto-increment ID (in PHP this is done with `$mysqli->insert_id`)
- create / get library ID by selecting/inserting with name
- insert new rental with those ID:s (do not use any title values)

The rental/borrower should also have own table with own ID field. Then just link those ID:s in rental table.

Answer (score 0):

When using `INSERT IGNORE`, errors like duplicate keys are ignored. The `AUTO_INCREMENT` key (the primary key of your table) will increase however, you cannot avoid this.

When using `INSERT [...] ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE [...]`, the `AUTO_INCREMENT` key will increase as well.

You can work around the problem

1. by two calls: a select for detecting whether the id already exists, and only call insert when the id is `null`
2. by creating a procedure for this purpose with the the two statements above, and call it from your backend.
3. You can reset the `AUTO_INCREMENT` value of the table too. This is neither a good practice, nor a fast solution, will increase the need of resources for simple tasks. I don't recommend considering this.

Comment: Well, strange but in local PC I have an issue, but in server there is no issue, I am running above written query and now auto_increment issue :) Maybe mysql versions makes a difference. Local pc v.4.0.4 and in server v.4.1.5   So, issue solved, Hardy and rekaszeru, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

you can avoid it by change default engine of my sql, you can change engine at time of create table like this:

```
create table if not exists category(BookId int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,BookTitle varchar(50),PRIMARY KEY(BookId),UNIQUE(BookTitle)) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```